# How to use sum values of matrix with filter

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading file using pandas. 
d= pandas.DataFrame("data.csv")

data.csv
       A   B             C

```
   d  408.56087701   87.26907024
   b 277.95015117   75.19386881 
   b 385.41416264   84.73488504 
   b 380.31630662   71.23504808 
   b 392.10729207   83.80720357 
   b  399.70877373   76.59640833 
   b 350.93124656   79.34979059 
   b 330.09702335   79.37166555
```

back= [399.70877373,385.41416264]

I am trying to sum values of C where I find match between "back" and column B

```
s=0
for indj, j in enumerate(back)
   for indi, i in enumerate(d) 
      if (j== i):
         s= s+d[indi][3]
```

I am trying to implement this using reduce :

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y,dat ..)
```

but i couldn't find a way to add condition to filter values ?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `back` instead of just using your original `data`?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this using

```
the_sum = sum(x[2] for x in data if x[1] in back)
```