# Sum values of array using zip

Tags: python

i have array of arrays this way. 
I wanna sum a specific fild (like 3rd in the list )

```
data = [[d, 408.56087701, 87.26907024],
        [b, 277.95015117, 75.19386881],
        [b, 385.41416264, 84.73488504],
        [b, 380.31630662, 71.23504808],
        [b, 392.10729207, 83.80720357],
        [b, 399.70877373, 76.59640833],
        [b, 350.93124656, 79.34979059],
        [b, 330.09702335, 79.37166555]]
```

I am trying this, but it produces problem as I have to select only 3rd in the list (first field is string)

```
data = [sum(x) for x in zip(*data)]
```

I have to add condition to show that x is third in sub list.

Comment: You seemed to be missing some commas. I edited them in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
the_sum = sum(x[2] for x in data)
```

Or if you're wondering why you thought `zip(*...)` seemed like a good idea in the first place:

```
the_sum = sum(zip(*data)[2])
```

Although that's more wasteful of memory

Comment: Thanks ! Can you take a look at this, I am trying to do filtering before I sum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974502/how-to-use-sum-values-of-matrix-with-filter